# Синхронизация данных: SQLite на Android + MySQL на Linux

Tags: android, sqlite, mysql

Есть приложение для таблетки на Android, которое хранит данные пользователя в SQLite. И есть удаленная база данных MySQL, которая хранит данные многих пользователей. Необходимо периодически синхронно либо асинхронно синхронизировать данные (преимущественно от мобильного клиента к удаленному серверу).

Какое готовое решение подходит лучше всего?

Comment: Сам сейчас такое делаю... про готовые решения не слышал, но Service еще никто не отменял.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще общепринятого средства нет. Из известных:

- Oracle Database Mobile Server + Oracle Database
- Microsoft Sync Framework (SQL Server, SQLite)
- Sybase SQL Anywhere Studio + UltraLite

Из малоизвестных:

- [QuickConnect](http://www.quickconnectfamily.org/qcdbsync/index.html)
- [WebSqlSync](https://github.com/orbitaloop/WebSqlSync)

Каркасы для разработки мобильных приложений типа *Sencha* и *RhoMobile* тоже включают модули по синхронизации данных.